# Full Build, Incremental Build and Deploy within Powerbuilder

Tags: deployment, build, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

What is the difference between a Full Build, an Incremental Build and Deploy within Powerbuilder? The only difference I can see is that Deploy allows you to update the PBDs for, well, deployment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full Build regenerates every object. Incremental Build regenerates changed objects and objects that reference changed objects. (Reality is that incremental is a little more complex than that, but that is the intended idea.) Deploy launches whichever project is selected in the properties for the target, so it can do an incremental or full build, depending on what is defined in the project, plus generate whatever executables are defined by the project.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Thanks Terry. To clarify, both Full and Incremental build options regenerate all objects, right?

Comment: No. Incremental regenerates only changed objects and objects referencing changed objects. This translates to, if you trust the algorithm used to generate this list, only objects that *need* regenerating. I've found a certain amount of skepticism about this algorithm is healthy, so I'm a big fan of full builds when things are "unexplainable."

Comment: I agree, I've had interesting results from incremental builds myself.  Full builds all the way.

Comment: I've had good luck with incremental builds using PowerGen for a number of years now.  Whatever is (used to be?) borked in the PB incremental build *just works* in PowerGen.

Answer (score 0):

I set my projects to Full build.  It seems to be more reliable than incremental.  Full build is very fast even on LARGE projects anyways.  There is not a lot of time savings using incremental build.

Deploy is used when you want to build the project AND run it immediately after the build.